# Get Visual Studio project name (or exe file name ) to use it inside a C++ program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I need to execute this command in my C++ program:

```
WinExec("program_name.exe", SW_SHOW);
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2010. Is there any way to use a variable, constant, or something, in order to avoid the string "program_name.exe"? Right now it is working in my computer, but my program will be tested in a different computer where I don't know the name of the project/exe file.

Comment: `GetModuleFileName(NULL)` gives you the full path to the calling EXE, if that's what you are looking for (it's not quite clear from the question).

Comment: `arv[0]` usually has the full path of the program.

Comment: try to have a configuration file, that would contain the name of the exe file, you can read the name inside the app to a string variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The executable name is passed as a parameter in the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    string exename = argv[0];
}
```

Comment: Is it just the exec name or may it also include the path?

Comment: I believe that argv[0] contains the first argument to in the shell command. This can either include the path or not and may depend on the system. Do not count on a path.

Answer (score 1):

*(To elaborate abdul's answer:)*

WinExec function check's the errors for you as you can see in the code below. If you are interested, you can read more about the WinExec function [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687393%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Let's take a look at the function syntax:

```
UINT WINAPI WinExec(
  _In_  LPCSTR lpCmdLine,
  _In_  UINT uCmdShow
);
```

Since `LPCSTR`(Long Pointer to Const String) is actually a `const string`, you can pass a string type as it's first argument, but you need to convert it to a const char*, which is actually a `LPCSTR`(Long Pointer to Const String). In the code below it is done by using `c_str()`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string appName="yourappname.exe";
   int ExecOutput = WinExec(appName.c_str(), SW_SHOW);
    /* 
    If the function succeeds, the return value is greater than 31.
    If the function fails, the return value is one of the following error values.
    0 The system is out of memory or resources.
    ERROR_BAD_FORMAT The .exe file is invalid.
    ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND The specified file was not found.
    ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND The specified path was not found.
    */
    if(ExecOutput > 31){
        cout << appName << " executed successfully!" << endl;
    }else {
        switch(ExecOutput){
        case 0:
            cout << "Error: The system is out of memory or resources." << endl;
            break;
        case ERROR_BAD_FORMAT:
            cout << "Error: The .exe file is invalid." << endl;
            break;
        case ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND:
            cout << "Error: The specified file was not found." << endl;
            break;
        case ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND:
            cout << "Error: The specified path was not found." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
   return 0;
}
```

I purposefully excluded the other function (that abdul created) to not delude from your question and to give you a clearer look at what you could actually do with the WinExec function. You could easily add that application checking function he created and put any other checks you need inside of it.

Comment: thanks, and also I am more familiar with linux system calls. the whole point was to get some thought up and as a jump start :) I meant to explain, but I suddenly had to be out. didn't get your sarcasm though even though I felt it internally :D make my day, +! for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the .exe file you want to run in the same location as the .exe that is running it, that way you could keep the hard coded constant name like it is.

Or a nice way would be to pass in the program name you want to run via the command line arguments, here is a tutorial for parsing the arguments:
[tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/13355/)

That way you can replace that string with a variable, and pass in the name via command line when you run the .exe.

Answer (score -1):

Open conf file
  read app name,
  test if app do exist
  save path,
  then pass to the function

this is just an example, same idea

```
int main()
{
   string appName;
   if (getAppName(appName)) 
   {
      WinExec(appName.c_str(), SW_SHOW);
     /// WinExec(appName, SW_SHOW);
     /// ^^^ one of these
   }
   return 0;
}
```

function looks like this

```
bool getAppName(string& appName)
{
   string str;
   ///file open, and read;
   ///read(str)
   if(fileExist(str))
   {
       appName = str;
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Refresh my memory, fileExist(string) is part of which header?

Comment: I am same as you :D the function name is not accurate, you probably either write your own function or use windows api. you can open the file and check the returned fd value, and then close, good but doesn't care or the content of file.

Comment: Hmm, you should have elaborated on that in your answer and you could just check the result of the WinExec method instead of improvising with that fileExist thing. WinExec checks it all for you.

Comment: Also, `str` is just an empty string, so even if `fileExist`...existed...in the API, it's checking for the existence of an empty filename. It's supposed to have the name of the .exe somehow.

Comment: @JimBuck Exactly, and I also didn't get the comments.

Comment: I cannot stop smiling, I do QNX programming professionally, so I dont deal much with windows api, although I wish I do.